# Simulation with Tidyverse -- putting data into tibble format

Tags: r, simulation, tidyr

I am trying to run simulations in R using the tidyverse. This code works, but doesn't scale well to more than a few variables.

Any thoughts on how to improve this? I've tried `purrr` but I didn't find any success.

The example below draws 5 values from a normal distribution and repeats this 3 times. How could I repeat it `n` times instead of 3?

```
n = 5

x=1:n
y1 = rnorm(n)
y2 = rnorm(n)
y3 = rnorm(n)

# put data into tibble
df <- tibble(x=x, y1=y1, y2=y2, y3=y3)

# Tidy data -- go from wide to long
df <- pivot_longer(df, cols=starts_with('y'))

# Make plot
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=value, group=name, color=name))+
  geom_line()
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we need to `replicate`, then

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
library(ggplot2)
n <- 5
rpl <- 3
replicate(rpl, rnorm(n), simplify = FALSE) %>% 
      set_names(str_c('y', seq_along(.))) %>%
      as_tibble %>%
      mutate(x = row_number()) %>%
      pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('y')) %>%
      ggplot(aes(x=x, y=value, group=name, color=name))+       
        geom_line()
```

Comment: It was very useful to know that `replicate(n, ..)` needs to be used rather than `rep(.., n)` which only runs the random generator once and pastes the output over n times. `replicate(n, ..) evaluates the `..` expr n times which is what we want with n instances of a random number generator